# <span> </span> in Table<td>

Tags: html

I have a time table as below:

```
<table id="timetable">
<tr><td>00:00</td><td id="tm0"></td></tr>
<tr><td>00:30</td><td id="tm1"></td></tr>
<tr><td>01:00</td><td id="tm2"></td></tr>
<tr><td>01:30</td><td id="tm3"></td></tr>
</table>
```

so if i want insert <span></span> into <td> start from id="tm0" - id="tm3"  how can i make it ?? instead of "rowspan" can anyone help ??

Comment: Why not rowspan? any particular reason? see http://jsfiddle.net/pTubK/

Comment: What is the use of id in your td, when you want to use span instead of rowspan. Make a table less timetable if you want to use the span. Much better give us more information what your trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

1. First get td elements using getElementById if you want frm 0 to 3 loop through the elements using something like ById("tm"+i).
2. Create the span element using creatingElement and set its properties.
3. Append this new element to the element retrieved in setp 1.

http://www.w3schools.com/DOM/dom_element.asp

But you are asking for this, in place of rowspan- which carries dynamic values. So i'm not user if i answered your query. But let us know why you want to use span in place of rowspan ?

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you can do it like following process:

```
$('table td:last-child').append('<span></span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Elements are arranged in a hierarchy. If the start tag for X is a child of Y, then the end tag for X must also be a child of Y.